# Propagate attriburte in custom view xml file to children

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that its layout holds an `EditText`.
I want that, in the xml layout file to add `android:imeOptions` or other, and let it propagate to the child `EditText`

Is there a way to do that, w/o custom attribute (for consistency)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, by retrieving the attribute value in your custom `ViewGroup`'s constructor, and setting it on the appropriate child `View`s as they're added, by overriding the `ViewGroup`'s `addView(View, int, LayoutParams)` method.

There are a few different ways to get that value from the `AttributeSet`. The following are examples using the `imeOptions` attribute.

---

Probably the most "standard" method would be to include the platform attribute in your `CustomViewGroup`'s `<declare-styleable>`, and retrieve its value just like you would for custom attributes.

In `res/values/`:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomViewGroup">
        <attr name="android:imeOptions" />
        ...
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In the Java code:

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
    private static final int IME_OPTIONS_NONE = -1;

    private int mImeOptions;

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomViewGroup);
        mImeOptions = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomViewGroup_android_imeOptions, IME_OPTIONS_NONE);
        ...
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);

        if (child instanceof EditText && mImeOptions != IME_OPTIONS_NONE) {
            ((EditText) child).setImeOptions(mImeOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, define the attribute array yourself, rather than through resources, and retrieve the value similarly.

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
    private static final int[] ANDROID_ATTRS = { android.R.attr.imeOptions };
    private static final int IME_OPTIONS_NONE = -1;

    private int mImeOptions;

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ANDROID_ATTRS);

        // 0 is passed as the first argument here because
        // android.R.attr.imeOptions is the 0th element in
        // the ANDROID_ATTRS array.
        mImeOptions = a.getInt(0, IME_OPTIONS_NONE);

        a.recycle();
    }

    // Same addView() method
}
```

---

Or, get the raw value directly from the `AttributeSet`, using the appropriate `getAttribute*Value()` method.

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    private static final String ATTR_IME_OPTIONS = "imeOptions";
    private static final int IME_OPTIONS_NONE = -1;

    private int mImeOptions;

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mImeOptions = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(NAMESPACE, ATTR_IME_OPTIONS, IME_OPTIONS_NONE);
    }

    // Same addView() method
}
```

---

If the attribute you want to propagate to the child `View`s is one that your custom `ViewGroup`'s super class already uses itself, then you don't necessarily need to read it from the `AttributeSet`. You could instead use the appropriate getter method to retrieve its value after the call to the `super` constructor, where it will have already been processed and applied.